# Diagonal Lines in NonSquare Array

Tags: java, c#

This should be a fairly straight-forward question but I cannot seem to figure out how to get all diagonals of a non-square matrix.

I already have what I consider the anti-diagonals (examples at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769730), but I need the opposite diagonal lines too.

Example Array:

```
1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9 10 11 12
```

Current output:

```
[1], [2,5], [3,6,9], [4,7,10], [8,11], [12]
```

Expected additional output:

```
[4], [3,8], [2,7,12], [1,6,11], [5,10], [9]
```

I'm looking more for pseudocode so I can understand this better.

EDIT: Code I have to get anti-diagonals (since no one seems to want to follow link)

```
int ndiags = width +  height - 1;
System.out.println("---");
for (int diag = 0; diag < ndiags; diag++) {
    int row_stop = Math.max(0,  diag -  width + 1);
    int row_start = Math.min(diag, height - 1);
    for (int row = row_start; row >= row_stop; row--) {
        // on a given diagonal row + col = constant "diag"
        // diag labels the diagonal number
        int col = diag - row;
        System.out.println(col + "," + row);
        relax(col, row);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
}
```

I tried the following, but I'm still just getting anti-diagonals:

```
int ndiags = width +  height - 1;
System.out.println("---");
for (int diag = 0; diag < ndiags; diag++) {
    int row_stop = Math.max(0,  diag -  height + 1);
    int row_start = Math.min(diag, width - 1);
    for (int row = row_start; row >= row_stop; row--) {
        // on a given diagonal row + col = constant "diag"
        // diag labels the diagonal number
        int col = diag - row;
        System.out.println(col + "," + row);
        relax(col, row);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
}
```

Comment: Post what you already have. Also, is this Java or C#?

Comment: Doesn't matter which - I can translate between the two

Comment: Still, you say in your question that you already have something. Could you post it and say what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize this code for any matrix...for now it prints correct output for above specified matrix

output: `[4 ] [3 8 ] [2 7 12 ] [5 10 ] [9 ]`

```
class Diagonal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int r=3,c=4;
        int Mat[][]={{1,2,3,4},{5, 6 ,7 ,8},{9,10,11,12}};

        int x,y;
        for(int i=c-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            y=i;x=0;
            System.out.print("[");
            while(y<c)
            {
                System.out.print(Mat[x][y]+" ");
                x++;y++;
            }
            System.out.print("] ");
        }

        for(int i=1;i<r;i++)
        {
            x=i;y=0;
            System.out.print("[");
            while(x<r)
            {
                System.out.print(Mat[x][y]+" ");
                x++;y++;
            }
            System.out.print("] ");
        }

    }
}
```

For anti-diagonal:

output: `[1 ] [2 5 ] [3 6 9 ] [4 7 10 ] [8 11 ] [12 ]`

```
class Diagonal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int r=3,c=4;
        int Mat[][]={{1,2,3,4},{5, 6 ,7 ,8},{9,10,11,12}};
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            y=i;x=0;
            System.out.print("[");
            while(y>=0 && x<r)
            {
                System.out.print(Mat[x][y]+" ");
                x++;y--;
            }
            System.out.print("] ");
        }

        for(int i=1;i<r;i++)
        {
            x=i;y=c-1;
            System.out.print("[");
            while(x<r)
            {
                System.out.print(Mat[x][y]+" ");
                x++;y--;
            }
            System.out.print("] ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to ask!

Comment: If you change `for(int i=1;i<r;i++)` to `for(int i=0;i<r;i++)` then it also includes main diagonal when array is square

Answer (score 1):

Each diagonal going in top-left to bottom-right direction is defined by `j - i` value where `i` is a row number and `j` is column number. Note that some of identifiers can be negative.

So pseudocode may be like this:

- Create a dictionary with `int` keys and `Linst<int>` values.
- Iterate over each element of the array.
- Append current element to the list identified by `j - i` value from dictionary.

In the end you can extract your lists from the dictionary in either way as items are sorted by integer key key. The sorting corresponds to the way of taking top-right or bottom-left diagonal first.

An advantage of this method is that you don't need to deal with your rectangular matrix dimensions and apply any checks. Just a single matrix traversal.

> could you show an example of what the list might look like?

The dictionary might look like this:

```
keys:   -2   -1   0   1   2   3
-------------------------------
lists:   9    5   1   2   3   4
             10   6   7   8
                 11  12
```

List elements are visualized from top to bottom.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this (probably because I've been looking at 2D for so long): could you show an example of what the list might look like?

Comment: I really like this solution - this is beyond my original question but do you think it would work for a 3D array too?

Comment: Yes it can be applied to 3D. The "diagonals" will be represented by surfaces for 3D matrix however. There will be 3 directions.