# Dynamic programming algorithm for n x n matrix of integers to find maximum sum

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am having quite difficulty to understand the following question, if some one can please help me out understanding it, I will be very grateful.
The question is:

```
Implement a dynamic programming algorithm for solving the following
problem. The input is an n × n matrix of integers. For the output: 
compute the largest sum of adjacent entries in horizontal, vertical,
diagonal and anti-diagonal direction. Return as output the sum 
h + v + d + c (in suggestive notation) of those four auxiliary results.
The largest (or maximal) sum of an array consisting of only negative  
integers is 0; that is, in that case we select the empty subarray.
A (small) example input matrix with solution 45:
|-2 5 3 2|
|9 -6 5 3|
|1 -8 2 -3|
|-1 2 -5 2|
```

I mean if some one can please help me towards the right direction,I will be really grateful!!! Thanks

Comment: What is unclear about this question?

Comment: @n247s thanks for your comment, so I don't understand this whole question clearly, basically what does it mean when it says adjacent entries in horizontal, vertical, diagnol and anti diagonal.

Comment: It means entries which are next to each other in a certain direction. For example -6 is vertically adjacent to 9, so is 5 and 3. (So all entries in that row)

Comment: thank you @SebastianWalla, but I don't understand how , because like in the matrix I have 4 rows, so how do I get the largest sum of adjacent entries in horizontal, I mean do I have to consider all 4 rows or its just adjacent entries in one row which has largest sum?

Comment: @Nia For the maximal sum of vertical entries I'd sum up each entry in a row and look for the maximum of them. For horizontal it would be summing up entries in each column and again look for the maximum of that four

Comment: @SebastianWalla Thank you so very much for helping me out and explains this, I really appreciate it!!!! I have just one tiny question, so do I sum all 4 entries or can I choose for example 2 adjacent of them incase other 2 out of 4 are negative?
Also I don't see how the sum of all should be 45 for above given matrix, Can you please also have a quick look at it to see if 45 is possible? And Again thanks a million!!!!

Comment: For the topmost horizontal row I believe you need to consider (the empty subarray, sum 0), -2, -2+5 = 3, -2+5+3=6, -2+5+3+2=8, 5, 5+3=8, etc. — quite many sums already. Take the largest and keep track of it. Now do the same for the next horizontal row. In the end, take the largest sum you got from any horizontal row. This is auxiliary result h. Find v (vertical), d (diagonal) and c (anti-diagonal) in similar ways.

Comment: In the example, I believe that h = 9+-6+5+3 = 11, v = 9+1 = 10, d = 5+5 = 10 and c = 9+5 = 14. Or maybe d and c are the other way around, it doesn’t matter. In any case 11 + 10 + 10 + 14 = 45 as the solution was supposed to be.

Comment: Hi @OleV.V. Thank you Sooooo much!!!!!!! okay I got it now, I really can't thank you enough for such nice explanation!!!! many thanks :)) Also a tons of thanks to Sebastian Walla for helping me out so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your problem statement:

> Implement a dynamic programming algorithm for solving the following
>   problem. The input is an n × n matrix of integers. For the output: 
>   compute the largest sum of adjacent entries in horizontal, vertical,
>   diagonal and anti-diagonal direction. Return as output the sum 
>   h + v + d + c (in suggestive notation) of those four auxiliary results.
>   The largest (or maximal) sum of an array consisting of only negative
>   integers is 0; that is, in that case we select the empty subarray.
>   A (small) example input matrix with solution 45:

```
|-2 5 3 2|
|9 -6 5 3|
|1 -8 2 -3|
|-1 2 -5 2|
```

Then, reading the example input you posted, I made a short method to parse that info from file:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> readFile(final String path) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    if (!Files.exists(p))
        return null;
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(p);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (lines == null)
        return null;
    for (String str : lines) {
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final String line = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
        String[] arr = line.split(" ");
        for (String s : arr)
            row.add(Integer.valueOf(s.trim()));
        result.add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The vertical approach is straight forward, looping through nested array.

```
    public static int getVertical(final List<List<Integer>> list) {
        int result = 0;
        for (List<Integer> arr : list) {
            int curr = 0;
            for (Integer val : arr)
                curr += val;
            if (curr > result)
                result = curr;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And the horizontal is also quite straight forward. Note: here I just used a list of counters for simplicity sake. There are more efficient approaches.

```
    public static int getHorizontal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
                sums.set(j, sums.get(j) + list.get(i).get(j));
        return Collections.max(sums);
    }
```

I quickly searched to find a diag/anti-diag loop [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420065/loop-diagonally-through-two-dimensional-array). This code was helpful to use in adapting to integer values (from strings/println's) and resulted in the following two methods. Note: the debug/system.out.println's are there for help/display.

```
    public static int getDiagonal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        int result = 0;
        // [top half]
        for (int i = len - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            //String temp = "";
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0, x = i; x <= len - 1; ++j, ++x) {
                final int val = list.get(x).get(j);
                //temp = temp + " " + val;
                tmp += val;
            }
            //System.out.println(temp);
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        // [lower half]
        for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; ++i) {
            //String temp = "";
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0, y = i; y <= len - 1; ++j, ++y) {
                final int val = list.get(j).get(y);
                //temp = temp + " " + val;
                tmp += val;
            }
            //System.out.println(temp);
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int getAntiDiagonal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        int result = 0;
        // [top half]
        for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; ++j) {
                int i = k - j;
                int val = list.get(i).get(j);
                //System.out.print(val + " ");
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
            //System.out.println();
        }
        // [lower half]
        for (int k = len - 2; k >= 0; --k) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; ++j) {
                int i = k - j;
                int val = list.get(len - j - 1).get(len - i - 1);
                //System.out.print(val + " ");
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
            //System.out.println();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here's what the entire program ended up looking like to solve the original question:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> data = readFile("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        for (List<Integer> row : data)
            System.out.println(row);
        final int n = data.size();
        int maxVertical = getVertical(data);
        int maxHorizontal = getHorizontal(data, n);
        int maxDiagonal = getDiagonal(data, n);
        int maxAntiDiagonal = getAntiDiagonal(data, n);
        System.out.println("max vertical = " + maxVertical);
        System.out.println("max horizontal = " + maxHorizontal);
        System.out.println("max diagonal = " + maxDiagonal);
        System.out.println("max anti-diagonal = " + maxAntiDiagonal);
    }
    public static int getVertical(final List<List<Integer>> list) {
        int result = 0;
        for (List<Integer> arr : list) {
            int curr = 0;
            for (Integer val : arr)
                curr += val;
            if (curr > result)
                result = curr;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int getHorizontal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
                sums.set(j, sums.get(j) + list.get(i).get(j));
        return Collections.max(sums);
    }
    public static int getDiagonal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        int result = 0;
        // [top half]
        for (int i = len - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0, x = i; x <= len - 1; ++j, ++x) {
                final int val = list.get(x).get(j);
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        // [lower half]
        for (int i = 0; i <= len - 1; ++i) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0, y = i; y <= len - 1; ++j, ++y) {
                final int val = list.get(j).get(y);
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int getAntiDiagonal(final List<List<Integer>> list, final int len) {
        int result = 0;
        // [top half]
        for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; ++j) {
                int i = k - j;
                int val = list.get(i).get(j);
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        // [lower half]
        for (int k = len - 2; k >= 0; --k) {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= k; ++j) {
                int i = k - j;
                int val = list.get(len - j - 1).get(len - i - 1);
                tmp += val;
            }
            if (tmp > result)
                result = tmp;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static List<List<Integer>> readFile(final String path) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        Path p = Paths.get(path);
        if (!Files.exists(p))
            return null;
        List<String> lines = null;
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (lines == null)
            return null;
        for (String str : lines) {
            List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            final String line = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            for (String s : arr)
                row.add(Integer.valueOf(s.trim()));
            result.add(row);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally, given the test.txt file contains:

```
|-2 5 3 2|
|9 -6 5 3|
|1 -8 2 -3|
|-1 2 -5 2|
```

Output result (should be) is:

```
[-2, 5, 3, 2]
[9, -6, 5, 3]
[1, -8, 2, -3]
[-1, 2, -5, 2]
max vertical = 11
max horizontal = 7
max diagonal = 7
max anti-diagonal = 14
```

Cheers

***Edit*** I realized I didn't technically answer the original question completely so:

1. added these two lines to the very end of the main() method

   int result = maxVertical + maxHorizontal + maxDiagonal + maxAntiDiagonal;
   System.out.println("Result = " + result);
2. Add checks to each respective method (vert/horiz/diag/anti-diag) so that the case for the negative occurrence stated in problem

> The largest (or maximal) sum of an array consisting of only negative
>   integers is 0; that is, in that case we select the empty subarray

is able to be covered as well. This isn't a huge code overhaul persay, moreso a unique check.

Comment: Hi Nick,
Thank you so much for such detailed explanation and such hard work to explain it. I am in your debt forever. Thank you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Your results don’t agree with the ones I calculated by hand in a comment, nor with the information in the assignment that the result should be 45. Summing your results: 11 + 7 + 7 + 14 = 39, not 45. I believe you’re close, though, and since the OP found this helpful, I am not trying to subtract from that. :-)

Comment: Many of us on Stack Overflow try to resist the temptation to write a solution for an asker. We generally think the asker will learn more from writing his or her solution himself/herself, so it is in her/his best interest. In this particular case the asker specifically asked for help understanding the assignment, not help on coding a solution. So though admiring your effort, I frankly think posting it here is out of place.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for your comments, I agree with you to some extent.I think myself about different approaches after understanding the question. For me the problem was that I did not understand what the question was , and that is why I posted here.
But its always nice to see different approaches and that's why I was very happy to see that some one spent so much time on it that they programmed it.You have also helped so much in understanding the basics of it, which I really needed to think about the solution my self. So many thanks for that and don't worry this girl is not a copy coder :)

Comment: I interpreted the problem statement as including summing negative numbers in any given sequence and only if the entire sequence is negative to change the sum to zero - not to negate all negative numbers to zero. Edit: `assignment`?

Comment: @NickBell My interpretation is the same.

Comment: Then I do not understand why you take 5,5,(no -3) for 10 diag, and other 10? Why sum not -3 to get 7? I am confused with either what you're saying or with the original post problem statement - could you help me clear up where I went wrong so I can try to fix my mistake?

Comment: Ah, @NickBell, now I think I understand the difference. In my understanding you may take any subarray of the row, column or diagonal. So for diagonal [5, 5, -3] you may take just 5 or [5, 5] or [5, 5, -3] or [5, -3]. You obtain the largest sum when you take [5, 5].

Comment: Thanks I more understand the problem now with that explanation!