# Get sum of parallel diagonals in matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

There is a square matrix *nxn*. The task is to determine the maximum among the sums of elements of diagonals which are parallel to the main diagonal of the matrix. I have managed already to loop throught matrix in proper way and output these elements. So how can I find the sum of every diagonal separately? Or at least how to extract every diagonal separately while looping throught matrix? Thanks in advance!

```cs
        //Reverse rows of matrix
        static int[,] Reverse2DimArray(int[,] theArray)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= (theArray.GetUpperBound(0)); rowIndex++)
            {
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex <= (theArray.GetUpperBound(1) / 2); colIndex++)
                {
                    int tempHolder = theArray[rowIndex, colIndex];
                    theArray[rowIndex, colIndex] = theArray[rowIndex, theArray.GetUpperBound(1) - colIndex];
                    theArray[rowIndex, theArray.GetUpperBound(1) - colIndex] = tempHolder;
                }
            }
            return theArray;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[,] reversed = Reverse2DimArray(matrix);
            MatrixOutput(reversed, size);
            for (int y = 0; y < 2 * size; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
                {
                    if (0 <= y - x && y - x < size)
                        Console.WriteLine(reversed[y - x, x]);

                }
            }
        }
```

What I have now:

```
3 6 2 9 5 1 8 4 7
```

What I need is:

```
             1  2  3
             4  5  6
             7  8  9
            Diadonals: 3; 6,2; 9,5,1; 8,4; 7
            Sums: 3; 8; 15; 19
            Output: 19
```

Comment: upd: I didn't post all the code. Only the most important parts.

Comment: Should anwer be Diadonals: 7,6,2; 9,5,1; 3,8,4;

Comment: @jdweng sorry, what? yep, it's my typo, but the outputs still being the same

Comment: Why are you multiplying in the y for loop : 2 * size

Comment: @jdweng because there are 2*size-1 parallel diagonals in matrix

Comment: So there are 7 diagonals for a 4 x 4 matrix?  And 5 diagonals for a 3 x 3?  You said you agreed with me that there were only 3 diagonals for a 3 x 3.

Comment: @jdweng seems to me, we didn't understand each other. So there are 7 diagonals in 4x4, 5 diagonals in 3x3. By saying diagonals I mean elements that are parallel to the main diagonal.  I wrote an example of matrix and what I mean by saying diagonals at the question.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20422854/3034273 Variant 2? The outer loop indicates which diagonal you're looking at.